# Chomp whitespace when autoclosing with smartparens?

Tags: smartparens

`electric-pair` has an `electric-pair-skip-whitespace` config that accepts `'chomp` to delete any whitespace between point and the matched closing delimiter. Does `smartparens` have something like that? I haven't found anything like that in the sample configs o wiki, but maybe it has a different name.

To clarify the behavior I'm looking for is:

```
{ abcd |
}

:=> type '}'

{ abcd }|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by providing some post-hooks manually (feel free to contribute useful code :).  Another setting is to enable `sp-navigate-reindent-after-up` which will reformat your sexps when you call `sp-up-sexp` (which in strict mode will be called when you hit `}` in your example --- or you can set `sp-autoskip-closing-pair` to `always`).

There is no global setting like the one electric-pair has, global settings led to great many problems in smartparens so we are trying to eliminate as much of them as possible.